# PCRE - Regex - Capture everything enclosed - first occurrence of pattern

Tags: regex

I am a newbie to writing regex.

I am trying to extract string between pattern, but want to extract only string before first occurrence of second pattern. Was trying to extract using "capture everything enclosed" in regex.

My String -

```
"contract":"476Q","prodId":"ABCD",
```

Looking for -

```
476Q
```

Regular Expression I tried -

```
contract":"(?<field>.*)",
```

This is giving me -

```
476Q","prodId":"ABCD
```

I understand this is taking until the end of the line to find the last occurrence of ", . Not sure how to stop until first occurrence of ",

Searched stack-overflow for other examples, but no luck;

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like your string is JSON. Can you just parse it programmatically? If you're using JS, for example, `JSON.parse(foo)`. If you have to use regex, `"contract":"(.*?)"` should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply ggorlen. I just pasted a part of the raw log. Part of the raw log contains JSON. The entire log is a mix of plan string with delimiter and JSON. The regex you suggested is working. Can i assign a name to the output field? something like "contract":"(.*?<field>)" ; This is not working. Can you please kindly help? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is working now :

"contract":"(?<fieldname>.*?)"

Appreciate your help !